# Unitary matrices are invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, unitary-matrices

I'm currently looking for the proof that a matrix $Q \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ that is unitary (i.e such that $QQ^*=I)$ is invertible and that $Q^* = Q^{-1}$.

Comment: For square matrices, [if $AB=I$, then $BA=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A square matrix $A$ is called invertible if there exists $B$ such that $AB=I$, the identity matrix.

Compare this with the equation $QQ^*=I$ and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

The condition that $Q^* Q= QQ^*= I$ by definition means that this is invertible, with inverse given by $Q^*$.